# disable arrow key on flowplayer scrollable

Tags: flowplayer, arrow-keys, scrollable

i need to disable the arrow keys in a flowplayer.org scrollable i have a text input that i cant move between the letters due to the scroller moving when arrow keys pressed, i dont care to disable the scroller keys permanently.

thanks

[link to scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.htm)

[link to forum to disable keys](http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/55/30548)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your scrollable instance to a variable:

```
var yourScrollable = $(".yourScrollableClass").eq(1).data("scrollable");
```

And then disable the keyboard navigation (in your case, on focus on a text input):

```
$('.inputClass').focus(function() { yourScrollable.getConf().keyboard=false; });
```

Then you can set this back to true on blur of your text input.

```
$('.inputClass').blur(function() { yourScrollable.getConf().keyboard=true; });
```

Comment: this is my actual code where do i place your code?
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  $("#myDiv").load( $(this).val(), function(){
 $(this).find("div.scrollable").scrollable();
} );
});
});
thanks!

Comment: Just before the last }); should work.  Replace ".yourScrollableClass" with ".scrollable" and '.inputClass' with whatever the class of the input in question is, or 'input' for all inputs (or 'textarea' if that).  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for getting back!
im getting this error 
yourScrollable is undefined
$('input').focus(function() { yourScrollable.getConf().keyboard=false; }); 

this is my code
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  $("#myDiv").load( $(this).val(), function(){
 $(this).find("div.scrollable").scrollable();
} );
});
var yourScrollable = $(".scrollable").eq(1).data("scrollable");
$('input').focus(function() { yourScrollable.getConf().keyboard=false; });
$('input').blur(function() { yourScrollable.getConf().keyboard=true; });
});

Comment: You might need to add a test for when pages don't contain a scrollable element.  To test if yourScrollable exists, you can change the interior of the focus and blur functions to: if (yourScrollable.length) { yourScrollable.getConf().keyboard=false; }
Good luck again!